# Here Fleet Telematics Waypoint Sequence has limited request a day

Tags: here-api

We are on testing the optimizing route, and the waypoints sequence. 
I used this API https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json

Everything is working well, but suddenly i got responseCode: 429 Daily limit of 10 requests has been reached

Is it Limited Request for Freemium?

Is it Limited Per Domain or IP or Server?

How do we extend this limited request?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSE has 10 requests limit per day per APP ID. Yes this limit restriction is for freemium accounts.

For Freemium plans only, the following limits apply:

```
Custom Locations: you may upload a maximum of 3 layers with a maximum of 100 polygons or polylines.
Waypoints Sequence: up to 10 requests per day.
Advanced Data Sets: up to 100 requests per hour and 1,000 per day.
```

Comment: thanks for the response, is it another limit restriction after upgrade plans? how many request per day?

Comment: There is no restriction on pro plans yet. You can refer to our faqs and plans page for more information.